# Setting a per-request proxy (or rotating proxies) with .NET Flurl/HttpClient

Tags: c#, flurl

I know that with the [Flurl](https://flurl.io/) HTTP .NET library I can set a global proxy by using a custom [`HttpClientFactory`](https://flurl.io/docs/configuration/#httpclientfactory), but **is there a way to choose a custom proxy for each request**?

With many other programming languages, setting a proxy is as easy as setting an option. For example, with Node.js I can do:

```js
const request = require('request');
let opts = { url: 'http://random.org', proxy: 'http://myproxy' };
request(opts, callback);
```

The *ideal* way to do that with Flurl would be something like this, which is currently not possible:

```cs
await "http://random.org".WithProxy("http://myproxy").GetAsync();
```

I also know that creating a `FlurlClient`/`HttpClient` for every request is not an option, because of the [socket exhaustion issue](https://aspnetmonsters.com/2016/08/2016-08-27-httpclientwrong/), which I've experienced myself in the past as well.

The scenario for this is when you need to have a pool of proxies that are rotated in some way, so that each HTTP request potentially uses a different proxy URL.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

So after some discussion with the Flurl creator ([#228](https://github.com/tmenier/Flurl/issues/228) and [#374](https://github.com/tmenier/Flurl/issues/374)), the solution we'come up with is to use a custom FlurlClient manager class, which would be in charge of creating the required `FlurlClient`s and the linked `HttpClient` instances. This is needed because each `FlurlClient` can only use one proxy at a time, for limitations of how the .NET `HttpClient` is designed.

**If you're looking for the actual solution (and code), you can skip to the end of this answer.** The following section still helps if you want to understand better.

[**UPDATE**: I've also built an HTTP client library that takes care of all the stuff below, allowing to set a per-request proxy out of the box. It's called [PlainHttp](https://github.com/matteocontrini/PlainHttp/).]

So, the first explored idea was to create a custom `FlurlClientFactory` that implements the `IFlurlClientFactory` interface.

The factory keeps a pool of `FlurlClient`s, and when a new request needs to be sent, the factory is invoked with the `Url` as the input parameter. Some logic is then performed to decide whether the request should go through a proxy or not. The URL could potentially be used as the discriminator for choosing the proxy to use for the particular request. In my case, a random proxy would be chosen for each request, and then a cached `FlurlClient` would be returned.

In the end, the factory would create:

- *at most* **one `FlurlClient` per proxy URL** (which will be then used for all the requests that have to go through that proxy);
- a set of clients for "normal" requests.

Some code for this solution can be found [here](https://github.com/tmenier/Flurl/issues/228#issuecomment-423838963). After registering the custom factory, there would be not much else to do. Standard requests like `await "http://random.org".GetAsync();` would be *automagically* proxied, **if** the factory decided to do so.

Unfortunately, this solution has a drawback. It turns out that **the custom factory is invoked multiple times** during the process of building a request with Flurl. According to my experience, it is called [at least 3 times](https://github.com/tmenier/Flurl/issues/374). This could lead to issues, because **the factory might not return the same `FlurlClient` for the same input URL**.

### The solution

The solution is to build a custom **`FlurlClientManager`** class, to completely bypass the FlurlClient factory mechanism and keep a custom pool of clients that are provided on demand.

While this solution is specifically built to work with the awesome Flurl library, a very similar thing can be done using the `HttpClient` class directly.

```cs
/// <summary>
/// Static class that manages cached IFlurlClient instances
/// </summary>
public static class FlurlClientManager
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Cache for the clients
    /// </summary>
    private static readonly ConcurrentDictionary<string, IFlurlClient> Clients =
        new ConcurrentDictionary<string, IFlurlClient>();

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets a cached client for the host associated to the input URL
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="url"><see cref="Url"/> or <see cref="string"/></param>
    /// <returns>A cached <see cref="FlurlClient"/> instance for the host</returns>
    public static IFlurlClient GetClient(Url url)
    {
        if (url == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(url));
        }

        return PerHostClientFromCache(url);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets a cached client with a proxy attached to it
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>A cached <see cref="FlurlClient"/> instance with a proxy</returns>
    public static IFlurlClient GetProxiedClient()
    {
        string proxyUrl = ChooseProxy();

        return ProxiedClientFromCache(proxyUrl);
    }

    private static string ChooseProxy()
    {
        // Do something and return a proxy URL
        return "http://myproxy";
    }

    private static IFlurlClient PerHostClientFromCache(Url url)
    {
        return Clients.AddOrUpdate(
            key: url.ToUri().Host,
            addValueFactory: u => {
                return CreateClient();
            },
            updateValueFactory: (u, client) => {
                return client.IsDisposed ? CreateClient() : client;
            }
        );
    }

    private static IFlurlClient ProxiedClientFromCache(string proxyUrl)
    {
        return Clients.AddOrUpdate(
            key: proxyUrl,
            addValueFactory: u => {
                return CreateProxiedClient(proxyUrl);
            },
            updateValueFactory: (u, client) => {
                return client.IsDisposed ? CreateProxiedClient(proxyUrl) : client;
            }
        );
    }

    private static IFlurlClient CreateProxiedClient(string proxyUrl)
    {
        HttpMessageHandler handler = new SocketsHttpHandler()
        {
            Proxy = new WebProxy(proxyUrl),
            UseProxy = true,
            PooledConnectionLifetime = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10)
        };

        HttpClient client = new HttpClient(handler);

        return new FlurlClient(client);
    }

    private static IFlurlClient CreateClient()
    {
        HttpMessageHandler handler = new SocketsHttpHandler()
        {
            PooledConnectionLifetime = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10)
        };

        HttpClient client = new HttpClient(handler);

        return new FlurlClient(client);
    }
}
```

This static class keeps a global pool of `FlurlClient`s. As with the previous solution, the pool consists of:

- **one client per proxy**;
- **one client per host** for all the requests that mustn't go through the proxy (this is actually the default factory strategy of Flurl).

In this implementation of the class, the proxy is chosen by the class itself (using whatever policy you want, e.g. round robin or random), but it can be adapted to take a proxy URL as the input. In that case, remember that with this implementation clients are never disposed after they're created, so you might want to think about that.

This implementation also used the new `SocketsHttpHandler.PooledConnectionLifetime` option, available since .NET Core 2.1, to solve the DNS issues that arise when your `HttpClient` instances have a long lifetime. On .NET Framework, the `ServicePoint.ConnectionLeaseTimeout` property should be used instead.

Using the manager class is easy. For normal requests, use:

```cs
await FlurlClientManager.GetClient(url).Request(url).GetAsync();
```

For proxied requests, use:

```cs
await FlurlClientManager.GetProxiedClient().Request(url).GetAsync();
```