# How to use Proxy with Flurl or HttpClient?

Tags: c#, proxy, httpclient, flurl

I'm a big fan of HttpClient, especially the Flurl wrapper. However, I have the following problem. I access an API resource, where they limit the number of requests per IP per day. I thought of a solution using 3rd party Proxy to access. Unfortunately, my knowledge is limited, and the documentation I find online is not very much about this, of course, HttpClient (or Flurl) is not designed to do this. I want every 5 or 10 requests to automatically change to a new proxy to avoid blocking access.
Thank you!

Comment: Please see this related answer on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52708836/setting-a-per-request-proxy-or-rotating-proxies-with-net-flurl-httpclient).

Comment: @sarin Great find!

Comment: I tried @mcont's code but it doesn't work. Are there any better sample snippets?